# Dependent Data Validation in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add Data Validation to a range of cells based on the State chosen in the previous cell.

I've run this code which works ok for a limited amount of data but is not working on the [actual spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s091ds4slnbN56vjEOhDcDu4O-bfRmUkgGi_W7ETg-4/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function onEdit(e) { // Runs automatically when the user edits the sheet

  var value = e.value; // Get the new value entered into the edited cell
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); // Get the column number of the edited cell
  var row = e.range.getRow(); // Get the row number of the edited cell

  
  if (col == 6 && row >= 10 && row <= 854) { // Make sure that the edited cell is part of the table
    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Localidades'); // Get the sheet that has the table with the list of cities
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("A1:X594").getValues(); // Get the table with the list of cities.
    
    var listOfCountries = dropdownData[0]; // The top row is the list of countries
    var countryColumn = listOfCountries.indexOf(value); // Find the column in which the country name appears
    
    if (countryColumn != -1) { // If the new country name is in the list
      var cityList = [];
      for (var dataRow = 1; dataRow < dropdownData.length; dataRow++) {
        cityList.push(dropdownData[dataRow][countryColumn]);
      }
      
      var cityCell = sheet.getRange(row, col + 1);
      
      cityCell
      .clearDataValidations() // Remove any existing data validation in the target cell
      .clearContent(); // Clear the cell
      
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(cityList, true).build();
      cityCell.setDataValidation(rule);
      
    }   
    
  }
  
}
```

I've debugged and it gets the CityList all right so don't know what's the problem really. Any help??

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue and your goal from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Did you know that simple triggers cannot run for more than 30 seconds.  I suspect may easily approach that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is a limited amount of allowed dropdown options

Through testing you can easily verify that it is 500 options.

So, if you hardcode `"A1:X594"` you are above the limit.

However, for most of the provinces in your data the amount of options is less than 594 and your array contains many empty values.

You can remove all duplicates inlcuding emoty values by filtering, e.g.

```js
cityList = cityList.filter(function (value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
})
```

As for the provinces where you have many entries (e.g. Buenos Aires), maybe you can try to subdivide it into smaller regions so you have less than 500 dropdown options per dropdown?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!